# View metadata refresh in MySQL

Tags: mysql, view, metadata

Like other RDBMS, view meta data is stored at view creation time.

From `CREATE VIEW` in the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

> The view definition is “frozen” at creation time, so changes to the underlying tables afterward [sic] do not affect the view definition.

I can't see a way to refresh this view meta data cleanly, unlike other RDBMS:

- SQL Server: `EXEC sp_refreshview 'MyView'`
- Oracle: `ALTER VIEW MyView COMPILE`

The system here appears to be "do this manually" with DROP/CREATE which isn't my style. The usual crowd who do this manual process are on leave so it falls to me this week.

I don't have a minion to nominate either: so any solutions please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the view's definition, run one of the following:

- `SHOW CREATE VIEW viewname\G`
- `SELECT * from information_schema.views where table_name='viewname'\G`

Here is a quick example:

```
mysql> show create table mytable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: mytable
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `age` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+-----+
| id | age |
+----+-----+
|  1 |  10 |
|  2 |  15 |
|  3 |  20 |
|  4 |   5 |
+----+-----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create view mytable_tens as select * from mytable where MOD(age,10) = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable_tens;
+----+-----+
| id | age |
+----+-----+
|  1 |  10 |
|  3 |  20 |
+----+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create view mytable_tens\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                View: mytable_tens
         Create View: CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=``@`` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `mytable_tens` AS select `mytable`.`id` AS `id`,`mytable`.`age` AS `age` from `mytable` where ((`mytable`.`age` % 10) = 0)
character_set_client: latin1
collation_connection: latin1_swedish_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from information_schema.views where table_name='mytable_tens'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       TABLE_CATALOG: def
        TABLE_SCHEMA: johnlocke
          TABLE_NAME: mytable_tens
     VIEW_DEFINITION: select `johnlocke`.`mytable`.`id` AS `id`,`johnlocke`.`mytable`.`age` AS `age` from `johnlocke`.`mytable` where ((`johnlocke`.`mytable`.`age` % 10) = 0)
        CHECK_OPTION: NONE
        IS_UPDATABLE: YES
             DEFINER: @
       SECURITY_TYPE: DEFINER
CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT: latin1
COLLATION_CONNECTION: latin1_swedish_ci
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Whichever method you choose, you can visibly see the query making up the view. You can sculpt the [**CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) using whatever is shown.

Hope this helps, and Welcome to the DBA MinionExchange  !!!

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't "clean". *Sigh*.

Comment: @gbn : I hear ya. Even as a MySQL DBA, I can easily say that MySQL is not ANSI compliant, or anything compliant for that matter. Maybe this should go in Meta as "What Constitutes Proper Database Administration?"

Comment: Ah well, I'll have a minion work on this ;-)  Cheers

Comment: >Rolando, what's that "\G" at the end of each query you wrote?